# Moss 2007 full crawl has not stopped crawling.

Tags: 2007

I started a full crawl over the weekend and right now the time ran is 90:41:46 which is abnormal amount of time. The successful files that have been crawled are 3393337 and the files in error are 22. Those numbers has not changed for 2 hours.  I have read that the issue maybe a database maintenance plan that included a rebuild index task but I am not sold on this theory since it would have presented itself before now. Does anybody have any ideas on the issue?

Answer (score 1):

What type of content are you crawling?  It's possible the search is still running and if it's indexing external content (like public web sites) that hasn't changed, the crawl log will indicate that activity and the index count won't be incrementing.

If it's hung, then the crawl should be canceled and restarted.

Comment: I completely agree with Eric, and cannot overstate the importance of the Crawl Log (success and errors).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did look logs and it is still running. I assumed since I have an incremental crawl run every 10 mins per day that a full crawl should take less time. Do you have any ideas how we could speed this up?

Comment: Break your content sources up into different search scopes could help.  It all depends on what you're trying to index.